# How can I evaluate next statement when null was returned in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I do something like the following JavaScript code, in Java?

```js
var result = getA() || getB() || getC() || 'all of them were undefined!';
```

What I want to to do is to continue evaluating statements or methods, until it gets something instead of `null`.

I would like the caller code to be simple and effective.

Comment: What do you want in `result` if all methods returns different stuff ?

Comment: @TAsk - So far, I want same class or super class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a method for it.

```
public static <T> T coalesce(Supplier<T>... ts) {
    return asList(ts)
        .stream()
        .map(t -> t.get())
        .filter(t -> t != null)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

code taken from: http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2013/12/08/null-coalescing-in-java-8/

**edit** As mentioned in the comments. Find below a small snippet how to use it. Using the `Stream` API has an advantage over using `vargs` as method parameter. If the values returned by the methods are costly and not returned by simple getters the `vargs` solution would evaluate all those methods first.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
...
static class Person {
    String name;
    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String name() {
        System.out.println("name() called for = " + name);
        return name;
    }
}

public static <T> T coalesce(Supplier<T>... ts) {
    System.out.println("called coalesce(Supplier<T>... ts)");
    return asList(ts)
            .stream()
            .map(t -> t.get())
            .filter(t -> t != null)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

public static <T> T coalesce(T... ts) {
    System.out.println("called coalesce(T... ts)");
    for (T t : ts) {
        if (t != null) {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person nobody = new Person(null);
    Person john = new Person("John");
    Person jane = new Person("Jane");
    Person eve = new Person("Eve");
    System.out.println("result Stream API: " 
            + coalesce(nobody::name, john::name, jane::name, eve::name));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("result vargas    : " 
            + coalesce(nobody.name(), john.name(), jane.name(), eve.name()));
}
```

**output**

```
called coalesce(Supplier<T>... ts)
name() called for = null
name() called for = John
result Stream API: John

name() called for = null
name() called for = John
name() called for = Jane
name() called for = Eve
called coalesce(T... ts)
result vargas    : John
```

As shown in the output. In the `Stream` solution the methods returning the values will be evaluated inside the `coalesce` method. Only two are executed, as the second call returns the expected `non-null` value. In the `vargs` solution all methods returning the values are evaluated before the `coalesce` method is invoked.

Comment: Not sure using java stream API for this use case is relevant (nor efficient) even if the OP ask for a Java8 solution.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be better with an example of how you call it (analogous to the OP's example).

Comment: @SubOptimal - Thanks, I had to replace  `return asList(ts)...` to `return Arrays.asList(ts)...`, but still, its good.

Comment: @ruakh You're right. I added an example which demonstrate how to use it and shows the difference to a solution using a `vargs` parameter.

Comment: oh, a static import, ok, got it.

Comment: @HirofumiOkino For the lazy typers. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal - Showing correct answer, usage, difference to vargs pattern, output evidence, description in such a short time, you are GREAT. I think I should call you a master of Jevi (?) .May the force be with you =)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use java8 stream API, then look at the SubOptimal's solution.

In pure Java, you can't write the same line as in javascript: java will be more verbose.

If your getter is not time/resource consuming and you do not care about calling them twice, you can do:

```
String result = getA() != null ? getA() :
    (getB() != null ? getB() :
       (getC() != null ? getC() :
           "default value"));
```

Else you can do it with plain if:

```
String result = getA();
if (result == null) {
    result = getB();
    if (result == null) {
        result = getC();
        if (result == null) {
             result = "default value";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That last one looks the clearest to me, describes exactly what it's doing

Comment: Thanks but creating nested codes in this kind of situation is not exactly my favorite.

Comment: I know, I know, but just keep in mind that stream API is not the golden bullet for all. You should read some really interesting articles on the subject: https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html  https://dzone.com/articles/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops Moreover, calling `MyHelper.coalesce(getA(), getB(), getC(), "default value")` will call every getters even if the first one is not null!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java 8 Optional. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getA().orElse(getB().orElse(getC().orElse("Unknown")));
}

public static Optional<String> getA() {
    return Optional.empty();
}

public static Optional<String> getB() {
    return Optional.empty();
}

public static Optional<String> getC() {
    return Optional.empty();
}
```